# Detect collision coming from outside to inside

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I detect collision coming from outside and not detect collision coming from inside to outside

[image]

I have a game when a player fires a bullet it returns after a while like a boomerang. But my problem is that it should NOT detect a collision when the bullet is coming from the player but it should detect collision when the bullet is returning. I've tried oncollisionenter2d and ontriggerenter2d but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

You could check the direction of the bullet and react (or ignore) accordingly. The exact implementation depends on how you are moving the bullet.

If you are using a Rigidbody, you have access to the `Vector3 velocity` field, which you can multiply with the bullet's distance from the player with `Vector3.Dot()`. If the result is negative, then the two vectors are pointing in opposite directions (which means the bullet is moving away from the player) and you simply `return` from the OnCollisionEnter call.